# Why the lead-time demand variance is not simply the variance of the product of two independent random variables?

Tags: demand-distribution

In many text books, I find that the variance of the lead-time demand, if the lead-time and demand are independent random variables is defined as:

\begin{align}
{\mathrm{var}}[LTD] = \mu_{LT}\cdot\sigma_D^{2}+\mu_D^{2}\cdot\sigma_{LT}^{2}
\end{align}

with expected value:

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[LT \cdot D] = \mu_{LT}\cdot\mu_{D}
\end{align}

The stated variance is only possible if the random variable is of the form:

\begin{align} {\mathrm{var}}[LTD]= {\mathrm{var}}[\sum_{i=1}^{LT} D_{i} + LT\cdot D] \end{align} and where in this term:

\begin{align} \sum_{i=1}^{LT} D_{i} \end{align}

**LT** is a constant and in the term:

\begin{align}
LT\cdot D
\end{align}

**D** is constant and if \begin{align} \sum_{i=1}^{LT} D_{i} \end{align} is independent from \begin{align} LT\cdot D \end{align}.

Here I observe the first contradiction, the random varible defined for the expected value is different from the one defined for its variance:

\begin{align}
LT \cdot D \neq \sum_{i=1}^{LT} D_{i} + LT\cdot D
\end{align}

If we continue to analyze this for the variance we obtain:

\begin{align}
{\mathrm{var}}[LTD] = {\mathrm{var}}[\sum_{i=1}^{LT} D_{i} + LT\cdot D] = {\mathrm{var}}[\sum_{i=1}^{LT} D_{i}]+{\mathrm{var}}[LT\cdot D] = \mu_{LT}\cdot\sigma_D^{2}+\mu_D^{2}\cdot\sigma_{LT}^{2}
\end{align}

This doesn´t seem right. The variable we are interested in is the demand during the lead-time period, where LT and D are independent from each other:

\begin{align}
{\mathrm{var}}[LTD] = {\mathrm{var}}[LT \cdot D]
\end{align}

We already know, that for 2 independent random variables, the variance of their product is determined by:

\begin{align}
{\mathrm{var}}[X \cdot Y] = {\mathrm{var}}[X] \cdot {\mathrm{var}}[Y]+{\mathrm{var}}[X] \cdot \mathbb{E}[Y]^{2} + {\mathrm{Var}}[Y] \cdot \mathbb{E}[X]^{2}
\end{align}

Therefore the variance of the lead-time demand should be:

\begin{align}
{\mathrm{var}}[LT \cdot D] =\sigma_{LT}^{2} \cdot \sigma_{D}^{2}+\sigma_{LT}^{2} \cdot \mu_{D}^{2} + \sigma_{D}^{2} \cdot \mu_{LT}^{2} \rightarrow days^{2} \cdot \frac{units^{2}}{days^{2}} + days^{2} \cdot \frac{units^{2}}{days^{2}} + \frac{units^{2}}{days^{2}} \cdot days^{2} = units^{2} \end{align}

and not this where even the units of measure do not make any sense:

\begin{align} \mu_{LT}\cdot\sigma_D^{2}+\mu_D^{2}\cdot\sigma_{LT}^{2} \rightarrow days\cdot\frac{units^{2}}{days^{2}}+\frac{units^{2}}{days^{2}} \cdot days^{2} = \frac{units^{2}}{days}+units^{2}
\end{align}.

Comment: "The stated variance is only possible if the random variable is of the form:

\begin{align} {\mathrm{var}}[LTD]= {\mathrm{var}}[\sum_{i=1}^{LT} D_{i} + LT\cdot D] "\end{align} 

What is your basis for saying this?

Comment: It is the only way in which this formula for the variance, makes any sense: \begin{align} \mu_{LT}\cdot\sigma_D^{2}+\mu_D^{2}\cdot\sigma_{LT}^{2} \end{align} being in this equation the first term independent from the second one: \begin{align} {\mathrm{var}}[\sum_{i=1}^{LT} D_{i} + LT\cdot D] = {\mathrm{var}}[\sum_{i=1}^{LT} D_{i}]+{\mathrm{var}}[LT\cdot D] \end{align}

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you saying that $\sum_{i=1}^{LT} D_i$ is independent of $LT \cdot D$ even though they both involve $LT?$

Comment: The formula for the variance of the sum of randomly many i.i.d. random variables (where the number of terms is independent of the individual terms) is derived in example 4f of Ross, "Introduction to Probability Models" (third edition). It is as stated in the first equation of your question.

Comment: @prubin exactly, this is the reason that this source states for regarding those two terms as independent [link] (https://www.kellogg.northwestern.edu/faculty/weber/decs-430/Notes_4_Random_variability.pdf): page 2 "As long as the length of the leadtime is independent of the daily demands, the
expected total demand will be E[D]E[LT], ..." So, this is exactly my question. 1) Why they need to make this assumption, when we already know the variance of the product of two independent random variables? 2) Why the units of the proposed variance do not make sense?

Comment: Your statement that $\mathrm{var[LTD]}=\mathrm{var}[LT\cdot D]$ is incorrect.